# SharePoint Online Webhook with ngrok "Access Denied"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, asp.net, webapi, webhooks

I am trying to follow bellow documentation of Microsoft
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks

`I have given below permission azure app`
[image]

`But when I send any POST request it gives me access denied`

[image]

**But my GET request always run without any error**

`My ngrok also works fine`
[image]

I feel that my token is not passing through while POST request. Can somebody guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you should add more permissions for your Azure AD app, `AllSites.Manage` or even `AllSites.FullControl`. `Read\Write` is more about the list items and not webhooks.

Comment: So, you mean to say we should have higher permission. Thank you for clarification it works like charm